# OSX - Find if phone is connected to the WIFI Network

Tags: linux, macos, bash, arp

I'm trying to programmatically find whether my phone is connected to the current Network, given that I know my device's mac Address.

Something like this SOMETIMES works:

```
arp -a | grep "11:11:11:11:11:11"
```

Although it takes quite a few seconds to find results. And sometimes it just does not work. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

In general using your ARP table as a mechanism for finding if a device is present will be unreliable.  This is because your machine will only have an ARP entry if it has recently seen an IP packet from the phone.

One (not advised way) to make the ARP/MAC lookup work reliably is to ping every address on the local network prior to trying to see what the ARP table contains.  This can work because the ping will do address resolution for each address as part of the ping process.  But pinging every possible address on the local network can be viewed as unsociable.

Another possibility is to use [Bonjour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)).  Bonjour allows devices to find each other via a broadcast mechanism that can work without regard to ARP.

Answer (score 0):

So, use `nmap`.
Or set a static IP, and just `ping` it.
Or if you have access to Linux, try something like:

```
sudo iw dev wlan0 station get <peer-MAC-address>
```